# I have a class file which does not output the result due to code segment being the wrong length

Tags: java, class, jvm, java-bytecode-asm, .class-file

Below is the hexdump of the class file in question. I have no idea about why this code doesn't run and it gives a **java.lang.ClassFormatError: Code segment has wrong length in class file fibo** when running in terminal using **java fibo.** Does anybody with a expertise in this understand why the code length is incorrect?

```
  

     //source code as requested
            public class fibo{

            public static void main(String args[]){
                System.out.println(fibonacci(10));
            }

         public static int fibonacci(int n)  {
                if(n == 0)
                    return 0;
                else if(n == 1)
                  return 1;
               else
                  return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
            }
```

```
ca fe ba be 00 00 00 34  00 1f 0c 00 19 00 1e 01 
00 16 28 5b 4c 6a 61 76  61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 53  
74 72 69 6e 67 3b 29 56  01 00 10 6a 61 76 61 2f 
6c 61 6e 67 2f 4f 62 6a  65 63 74 01 00 06 3c 69  
6e 69 74 3e 07 00 03 0c  00 04 00 0a 07 00 13 0a  
00 07 00 1c 01 00 09 66  69 62 6f 2e 6a 61 76 61  
01 00 03 28 29 56 07 00  16 01 00 04 43 6f 64 65  
01 00 04 66 69 62 6f 01  00 04 6d 61 69 6e 01 00  
0d 53 74 61 63 6b 4d 61  70 54 61 62 6c 65 09 00 
0b 00 01 01 00 0a 53 6f  75 72 63 65 46 69 6c 65  
01 00 04 28 49 29 56 01  00 13 6a 61 76 61 2f 69  
6f 2f 50 72 69 6e 74 53  74 72 65 61 6d 01 00 07  
70 72 69 6e 74 6c 6e 0a  00 05 00 06 01 00 10 6a  
61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67  2f 53 79 73 74 65 6d 01  
00 04 28 49 29 49 0c 00  1b 00 17 01 00 03 6f 75  
74 07 00 0d 01 00 09 66  69 62 6f 6e 61 63 63 69 
0c 00 14 00 12 0a 00 1a  00 18 01 00 15 4c 6a 61 
76 61 2f 69 6f 2f 50 72  69 6e 74 53 74 72 65 61  
6d 3b 00 21 00 1a 00 05  00 00 00 00 00 03 00 01  
00 04 00 0a 00 01 00 0c  00 00 00 11 00 01 00 01  
00 00 00 05 2a b7 00 15  b1 00 00 00 00 00 09 00  
0e 00 02 00 01 00 0c 00  00 00 18 00 02 00 01 00  
00 00 0c b2 00 10 10 0a  b8 00 1d b6 00 08 b1 00
00 00 00 00 09 00 1b 00  17 00 01 00 0c 00 00 00  
37 00 03 00 01 00 00 00  1b 1a 9a 00 05 03 ac 1a 
04 a0 00 05 04 ac 1a 04  64 b8 00 1d 1a 05 64 b8 
00 1d 60 ac 00 00 00 01  00 0f 00 00 00 04 00 02  
06 06 00 01 00 11 00 00  00 02 00 09
```

Comment: How did you get this class file in the first place? Rather than dumping the result, it would be clearer if you'd provide a [mcve] which *produces* invalid code.

Comment: I would not look at the output; but on the way how you created it.

Comment: @JonSkeet ... might I ask you for a small favor?

Comment: I would like to know what is incorrect about this. Sure I will edit the question and attach the source code.

Comment: Are you saying this class file was created using a regular Java compiler with that source file? (Well, presumably a complete source file, which that isn't...) Which compiler?

Comment: Yes this is compiled using the Java compiler. if I ran the class file using java -noverify it outputs 55 which is correct. However, without "noverify" I get the exception described above

Answer (score 0):

Your class file is bad.  Copy the source (since you have it) into the IDE of your choice and rebuild it (usually in a menu called Build, Run, or Project).

I took your source code, added the missing brace at the end, compiled it, and ran it using `java fibo` and it worked just fine.  As a side note, Java classes should start with capital letters.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.  Do you know what is bad about it? why the "code segment has wrong length". if you compare mine to the one you produced are you able to tell me what the problem is with mine?

Comment: If this is a recurring problem you're having, you should reinstall Java and your IDE. There's really no reason to do a byte-for-byte comparison, as it probably wouldn't yield anything useful. I can post the compiled class of you still want it, but I doubt anything of worth will come of it. As far as the specific error, I'd try searching for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end it’s only one byte that is incorrect. As the exception tells you, there is one `Code` attribute in the class file that has an incorrect length. The fact that it has an incorrect length can be deduced from [its internal structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3), which allows to calculate the length, it should have. Without looking at the internal structure, a parser would break after the method, by attempting to interpret the wrong subsequent bytes as class attributes.

Your class has a compiler generated constructor, followed by the `main` method, finally followed by the `fibo` method, which is the one having a `Code` attribute of length 55 (hex: 37), which should be 49 (hex: 31). So in your hex dump

```
ca fe ba be 00 00 00 34  00 1f 0c 00 19 00 1e 01 
00 16 28 5b 4c 6a 61 76  61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 53  
74 72 69 6e 67 3b 29 56  01 00 10 6a 61 76 61 2f 
6c 61 6e 67 2f 4f 62 6a  65 63 74 01 00 06 3c 69  
6e 69 74 3e 07 00 03 0c  00 04 00 0a 07 00 13 0a  
00 07 00 1c 01 00 09 66  69 62 6f 2e 6a 61 76 61  
01 00 03 28 29 56 07 00  16 01 00 04 43 6f 64 65  
01 00 04 66 69 62 6f 01  00 04 6d 61 69 6e 01 00  
0d 53 74 61 63 6b 4d 61  70 54 61 62 6c 65 09 00 
0b 00 01 01 00 0a 53 6f  75 72 63 65 46 69 6c 65  
01 00 04 28 49 29 56 01  00 13 6a 61 76 61 2f 69  
6f 2f 50 72 69 6e 74 53  74 72 65 61 6d 01 00 07  
70 72 69 6e 74 6c 6e 0a  00 05 00 06 01 00 10 6a  
61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67  2f 53 79 73 74 65 6d 01  
00 04 28 49 29 49 0c 00  1b 00 17 01 00 03 6f 75  
74 07 00 0d 01 00 09 66  69 62 6f 6e 61 63 63 69 
0c 00 14 00 12 0a 00 1a  00 18 01 00 15 4c 6a 61 
76 61 2f 69 6f 2f 50 72  69 6e 74 53 74 72 65 61  
6d 3b 00 21 00 1a 00 05  00 00 00 00 00 03 00 01  
00 04 00 0a 00 01 00 0c  00 00 00 11 00 01 00 01  
00 00 00 05 2a b7 00 15  b1 00 00 00 00 00 09 00  
0e 00 02 00 01 00 0c 00  00 00 18 00 02 00 01 00  
00 00 0c b2 00 10 10 0a  b8 00 1d b6 00 08 b1 00
00 00 00 00 09 00 1b 00  17 00 01 00 0c 00 00 00
 this byte should be 31
 ↓ 
37 00 03 00 01 00 00 00  1b 1a 9a 00 05 03 ac 1a 
04 a0 00 05 04 ac 1a 04  64 b8 00 1d 1a 05 64 b8 
00 1d 60 ac 00 00 00 01  00 0f 00 00 00 04 00 02  
06 06 00 01 00 11 00 00  00 02 00 09
```

When changing this byte, the class will work without problems. How this byte became wrong, is impossible to say without context. A compiler should normally produce correct byte code and I never encountered such a kind of error with a normal compiler.